# Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I'm trying to upgrade a WCF web service from .NET 3.0 to 4. I've run

```
Aspnet_regiis.exe
```

and

```
ServiceModelReg.exe
```

As well as changed the Application Pool to use v4.0. I rebuilt the service dll with .NET 4.0 as the target and moved it to the /bin directory on my site.

I'm running into an error that is driving me nuts. Whenever I try to hit the site, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

> The configuration section
>   'system.serviceModel' cannot be read
>   because it is missing a section
>   declaration

I've tried solutions I've found from googling and nothing is working. I feel like someone more experienced with IIS 7 would know exactly what's wrong. Can anyone help with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I needed to install the [hotfix described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958854), which is step 3 in the "One-time setup procedure for WCF samples" for [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751527.aspx) WCF code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Try aspnet_regiis.exe /iru

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could check:

1. Did you change the WCF references in your application to the Framework 4.0 versions?
2. Here's a Microsoft support article: [Error message after you install the .NET Framework 4.0: "Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule'"](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=2015129):

   > This issue occurs because the Applicationhost.config file for Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) has the following section defined, and this section is incompatible with the .NET Framework 4.0 [...]
3. .svc: ensure that IIS and WCF are correctly installed and registered: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to do #3, but ".net framework 4 components" does not show up under add windows components.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure WCF HTTP Activation feature is installed in Server Roles/Features (it will be the 3.5 version), then re-install .NET Framework 4.0.  (You will have to install it from the download, its not part of Windows components/features)

If you're lucky, that should re-register the scriptmaps in such a way that .NET 4 will successfully receive WAS HTTP Activation requests from IIS instead of bypassign to 3.5 which doesnt understand what its being asked to do.

In theory, **aspnet_regiis /i** from the .NET Framework 4.0 directory should do this as well, but you said you already tried that.